# How to pass Image from View to Bootstrap Modal in MVC?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I want to pass filepath from view to Modal. But currently, the value of `filepath` is getting `undefined`.

Please guide me where I am getting wrong.

Script

```
  var row;
    $(document).on('click', '.mdlEdit', function () {
        debugger;
        row = $(this).closest('tr');   

        var link = $.trim(row.find('.Link').text());
       var filepath = $(this).data("Id");    

        $('#Title').val(title);
        $('#Link').val(link);

        $('#filePath').attr('src', filepath);

    })
```

Piece of code from view

```
<tr>
    <td class="Title">
        @item.Title
    </td>
    <td class="Link">
        @item.Link
    </td>

    <td class="filePath">
    <a target="_blank" data-id="@item.FilePath" href=@item.FilePath title="Enlarge Image">
                @Html.Image(item.FilePath, "Image", "60px", "", "img-thumbnail")
      </a>
    </td>
 <td>
  <a class="mdlEdit" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#EditRecord">Edit</a>

  </td>
</tr>
```

Custom Image Html Helper

```
public static IHtmlString Image(this HtmlHelper helper, string src, string alt, string height, string width, params string[] allClasses)
{
    TagBuilder tb = new TagBuilder("img");
    tb.Attributes.Add("src", VirtualPathUtility.ToAbsolute(src));//throws error
    tb.Attributes.Add("alt", alt);
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(height) || !string.IsNullOrEmpty(width))
    {
        StringBuilder value = new StringBuilder();

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(height))
            value.AppendFormat("height:{0};", height);

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(width))
            value.AppendFormat("width:{0};", width);

        tb.Attributes.Add("style", value.ToString());
    }
    if (allClasses?.Any() ?? false)
        tb.Attributes.Add("class", string.Join(" ", allClasses));

    return new MvcHtmlString(tb.ToString(TagRenderMode.SelfClosing));
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need:

```
var row = $(this).closest('tr');
var filepath = row.find('td.filePath a').data('id');
```

As you already specified `data-toggle="modal" data-target="#EditRecord"` in your Edit link, all you need is adding the dialog to the Html and setting a value to be displayed: `$('#modalContent').text(filepath);` as shown in following snippet.

and finally copy src attribute:

```
$('#EditRecord .img-thumbnail').attr('src', filepath);
```

```js
$(document).on('click', '.mdlEdit', function() {
  var row = $(this).closest('tr');

  var filepath = row.find('td.filePath a').data('id');

  $('#modalContent').text(filepath);
  $('#EditRecord .img-thumbnail').attr('src', filepath);
})
```

```css
a.mdlEdit:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: cyan;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="filePath">
      <a target="_blank" data-id="https://farm2.staticflickr.com/1070/553600544_dd5b2f39ec_m.jpg" href="https://farm2.staticflickr.com/1070/553600544_dd5b2f39ec_m.jpg" title="Enlarge Image">
        <img src="https://farm2.staticflickr.com/1070/553600544_dd5b2f39ec_m.jpg" alt="Image" style="height:60px;" class="img-thumbnail" />
      </a>
    </td>
    <td>
      <a class="mdlEdit" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#EditRecord">Edit modal</a>

    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="filePath">
      <a target="_blank" data-id="https://farm2.staticflickr.com/1125/553600532_3b70325b49_m.jpg" href="https://farm2.staticflickr.com/1125/553600532_3b70325b49_m.jpg" title="Enlarge Image">
        <img src="https://farm2.staticflickr.com/1125/553600532_3b70325b49_m.jpg" alt="Image" style="height:60px;" class="img-thumbnail" />
      </a>
    </td>
    <td>
      <a class="mdlEdit" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#EditRecord">Edit modal</a>

    </td>
  </tr>
</table>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="EditRecord" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Edit record dialog</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <div id="modalContent"></div>
        <img alt="Image" style="height:60px;" class="img-thumbnail" />
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you. Now I am getting the value. But how to send that to modal. As you can see I have used `<a target="_blank" data-id="@item.FilePath" href=@item.FilePath title="Enlarge Image">
                @Html.Image(item.FilePath, "Image", "60px", "", "img-thumbnail")
      </a>`

Comment: Many of them has provided `$('.filePath').attr('src', filepath);` but I do not have anything called `src`

Comment: I believe src is the source of the img tag but you seem to be using a custom helper for the image. Just show us the Html that's rendering.

Comment: Can you please have a look on custom helper method. I updated in question. Please help!

Comment: @MVC, based on your code I figure out the Html for the image has class img-thumbnail, so I'm using the class for selecting the img tag and changing the source attributte.

Comment: Thank you so much. It really helped me. I was missing `$('#EditRecord .img-thumbnail')` before.Simple and easy to understandable.

Answer (score 2):

it seems you are using "id"

```
$('#Title').val(title);
$('#Link').val(link);
$('#filePath').attr('src', filepath);
```

in td it is class="Title"

it must be

```
$('.Title').val(title);
$('.Link').val(link);
$('.filePath').attr('src', filepath);
```

and $('#filePath').attr('src', filepath); there is no attr like src for .filePath, attr is for a tag

Comment: Charan, I am getting `$(this).data("id")` `undefined`

Comment: Also, `$('.filePath').attr('src', filepath);` where I do not have `src` element in my code so how can it access.

Answer (score 2):

```
 var row;
    $(document).on('click', '.mdlEdit', function () {
        debugger;
        row = $(this).closest('tr');   

        var link = $.trim(row.find('.Link').text());
       var filepath = $(this).prop('data-id');  //add this line  

        $('.Title').val(title);
        $('.Link').val(link);

        $('.filePath a').attr('src', filepath);

    })
```

Comment: still getting `undefined`

Comment: Also, `$('.filePath').attr('src', filepath);` where I do not have `src` element in my code so how can it access.

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for `$(this).data("Id")` (capital I) when the actual data attribute is not with a capital i.
Also, as charan kumar said, you need to change '#' to '.' because you're using classes and not ids.

One more point. In the HTML you posted there is no element with "mdlEdit" class (which is the element you listen to its click event).

Comment: Sorry, I changed `$(this).data("Id")` to `$(this).data("id")` but still showing undefined. I am getting other values from `Title` and others too.

Comment: Do $(this).data(). what do you get? it returns all the properties of the data object.

Comment: If I do this $(this).data() then it gives me `filepath={target:"EditRecord",toggle:"modal"}`

Comment: are you sure the click event you're seeing is from the `<a>` in the html you posted? it looks like you're looking on the wrong element.

Comment: @MVC, because you are getting Edit tag `<a class="mdlEdit"...` which doesn't have data-id. You probably want to get `<a target="_blank" data-id="@item.FilePath"...`. Change that selector.

Comment: @derloopkat, I want to get the value of `@item.FilePath`. Please suggest me.

Comment: @Programmer, It hits the control and also getting other values except this `$(this).data("id")`

Comment: If you use `attr('href'')` instead of `data('id')`, you get the filePath?

Comment: @item.FilePath from where?

Comment: @derloopkat @item.FilePath is the value of `data-id` of the element and the `href`.